# Rewrite Mail Body in Outlook through Python Script

Tags: python, outlook, office365

Our company has recently added an automatic filter to all incoming Emails (O365) that rewrites URLs to some redirection service that is both unreliable and buggy. Additionally I hate it if a link is replaced by some garbage service I have not opted in to. Imagine it like a man-in-the-middle attack on your inbox.

So I wrote a Python script that can replace the rewritten links with the original ones. Currently I'm saving the email contents to a file, use the script and then copy & paste the output back. Evidently, this is not a good solution.

What I am trying to achieve is a way to do this automatically from inside Outlook, but I am open to other suggestions. I would like a solution to use Python since I'm comfortable with it, but if there is a different way that can handle this problem I'm open for that also.

Comment: How do you access outlook ? app or browser

Comment: Over the App on Windows 10